# Tree structure to get parent node and its children

Tags: c#, linq

Please find the table  structure below:

```
Folderid                    parentFolderid              Guid
1                           0                           1234
2                           1                           5678
3                           2                           9012
4                           3                           87697
5                           7                           4443
```

The requirement is if I pass folderId the function has to give me all the guids.

For example:If I pass `1` to the function, I should get first four Guids(parent and its children).
I have a function which returns all the guids as follows:

```
public List<Guid> Folders(int folderId)
{ 
    // To get the folderids based on parentfolderid
    var a = entity.Where(x => x.parentfolderId == folderId).FirstOrDefault();
     return a;

}
```

I am able to get only up to one level of ids.

Is there any way to get parent, its children, grandchildren till the leaf?

Comment: Sould it get grand-children as well?

Comment: Yes it has to even get the granchildren and also till the leaf.I forgot to mention that

Comment: There you go. Sorry, had to review the answer.

Comment: You might want to give us actual code. There's so many spelling/case mistakes in that snippit that there's no possible way it compiles.

Comment: @Kivin I just wanted the logic to get until the leaf in one shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to get that table to a class, check this out:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static List<Entity> GetTree(int ID, List<Entity> ListToSearch, bool First = true)
    {
        List<Entity> FilteredEntities = new List<Entity>();

        FilteredEntities.AddRange(ListToSearch.Where<Entity>(x => x.ParentID == ID).ToList<Entity>());

        List<Entity> Temp = new List<Entity>();
        foreach (Entity current in FilteredEntities)
        {
            Temp.AddRange(GetTree(current.ID, ListToSearch, false));
        }

        FilteredEntities.AddRange(Temp);

        if (First)
        {
            FilteredEntities.Add(ListToSearch.Where<Entity>(x => x.ID == ID).Single<Entity>());
        }

        return FilteredEntities;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    List<Entity> filteredEntities = Entity.GetTree(1, entities);
    List<string> onlyTheNames = filteredEntities.Select<Entity, string>(x => x.Name).ToList<string>();
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you use this [node class](https://www.siepman.nl/blog/a-generic-tree-of-nodes-the-easy-way), you can write the code like this.

```
public class Folder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Guid SomeGuid { get; set; }
}
```

and and example of what possible is:

```
var list = new List<Folder>
{
    new Folder {Id = 0, ParentId = null, SomeGuid = new Guid("0000b25b-8538-4b78-818a-9094507e0000") },
    new Folder {Id = 1, ParentId = 0, SomeGuid = new Guid("1000b25b-8538-4b78-818a-9094507e0001") },
    new Folder {Id = 2, ParentId = 1, SomeGuid = new Guid("2000b25b-8538-4b78-818a-9094507e0002") },
    new Folder {Id = 3, ParentId = 1, SomeGuid = new Guid("3000b25b-8538-4b78-818a-9094507e0003") },
    new Folder {Id = 4, ParentId = 2, SomeGuid = new Guid("4000b25b-8538-4b78-818a-9094507e0004") },
    new Folder {Id = 5, ParentId = 3, SomeGuid = new Guid("5000b25b-8538-4b78-818a-9094507e0005") },
    new Folder {Id = 6, ParentId = 0, SomeGuid = new Guid("6000b25b-8538-4b78-818a-9094507e0006") },
    new Folder {Id = 7, ParentId = 4, SomeGuid = new Guid("7000b25b-8538-4b78-818a-9094507e0007") },
    new Folder {Id = 8, ParentId = 3, SomeGuid = new Guid("8000b25b-8538-4b78-818a-9094507e0008") },
};
var rootNode = Node<Folder>.CreateTree(list, n => n.Id, n => n.ParentId).Single();

var firstChild = rootNode.Children.First(); // Id 1
var descendentsOfFirstChild = firstChild.Descendants; // All descendants of node 1
```